# 19.04 upgrade aborted after attempt to upgrade from 18.10 with message about unstable state

Tags: upgrade, 19.04

I saw few warning related to 'install menu' issues, But after all with message unstable state upgrade got aborted.
Any known issues with the most recent build?

Comment: i got the same type of messages yesterday after upgrading to 19.04 the message say computer is left in an unusable state but after restart i can not find any major problems the only thing was the upgrade ended before the cleanup of obsolete packages was initiated but this is not a problem.only errors during install was the usual pixbuf error several times.

Comment: I have the same issue. However everything is working, but it does cause some alarm. Not good for newbies.

Comment: Same here: (i) upgrade aborted with the (now) famous "unusable state warning"; (ii) rebooted with no apparent problem; (iii) myself living in an unustable mood afterwards...