# Ubuntu release update stuck

Tags: upgrade, 18.10, 19.04

I am updating from 18.10 to 19.04 but my updating process is stuck. At first it just took forever to do anything and some tasks timed out but now it hasn't porgressed at all for an hour. Task manager is unresponsive aswell. I can open other applications but they are unresponsive aswell. What should I do now? I am scared restarting etc. will corrupt my files.

Edit

I can open another terminal and run commands from there, e.g. top works and shows me the active tasks

Edit
Resolved

Comment: Can you tell whether it was downloading, unpacking or configuring packages?

Comment: It's stuck on configure nfs-kernel-server (1:1.3.4-2.3ubuntu3)

Comment: You should be able to kill the update process, remove `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` and try again.

Comment: How do I remove that x)

Comment: Open a termninal, enter `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock` and enter your password when prompted.

Comment: If i try it with sudo the terminal gets stuck, without sudo i get the normal response 'no permission'

Comment: Does this work: `sudo dpkg --configure -a `?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93771/discussion-between-yamahari-and-jos).

Comment: this might be related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135419/19-04-upgrade-aborted-after-attempt-to-upgrade-from-18-10-with-message-about-uns it does not have an answer yet.